# How to send an error to Android phone upon writeCharacteristic() being called?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

`onCharacteristicWrite()` is being called with a status code of 0 in my `BluetoothGattCallback` object on Android (SDK 28).

I'm working with a Bluetooth Device for which my team is writing both the firmware and Android (and iOS, Windows, Mac, etc.) software to interact with the firmware.

We have a situation where the mobile application writes some data to a characteristic and depending on the data being sent, an error should be issued by the BLE device.

On iOS, sending a vendor specific error code results in an `UNKNOWN ATT Error`, but on Android a status code of 0 is passed to `onCharacteristicWrite()`.

Is there a way to get the error code from the **Android BLE stack**?

Is there any kind of way to escalate the problem to someone who would understand how to do this such as a paid support channel at Google?

Comment: I haven't read through all of the Bluetooth specification. But is there really such a thing a *vendor specific error codes*? And why go to all the troubles with error codes anyway? Why not use a separate characteristic with notifications?

Comment: You should be able to use an "Application Error" code (0x80-0xFF), preferably some that doesn't clash with other Android specific error codes such as 128, 133. It will be passed to the status argument to the onCharacteristicWrite callback.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting an error code of 0 was that I needed to call setWriteType(WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT) on the characteristic so that it would return a response. This resulted in my now getting error 254 when the part sends back an application error. I used the wrong term "vendor specific error" in my question.